# lstlisting vs csname problem with "Text dropped after beginning of listing"

Tags: listings, etoolbox

For my class, I write exercises; I also include the solutions (for me and the TAs). I like to process a single document, but set a "flag" to say whether to produce solutions or not. [This](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/331051/testing-whether-a-name-is-defined-after-building-up-the-name) answer helped me make that work. But when I include a "lstlisting" within the optional material, things no longer work properly:

```
\documentclass{article}
\RequirePackage{listings}
\RequirePackage{etoolbox}

\newcommand{\solflag}{}

\newcommand{\version}[2]
{\ifcsdef{#1flag}{#2}{}}

\begin{document}

Before.

\version{sol}{
\begin{lstlisting}[language=C]
  // An example of a C comment.
\end{lstlisting}
}

After.
\end{document}
```

Processing this with pdflatex on my Linux machine produces a warning (`Package Listings Warning: Text dropped after begin of listing on input line 18.`) followed by an "asterisk-waiting-for-input" state.

From [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/95053/text-dropped-after-beginning-of-listing), I see that stuff after `\begin{lstlisting}` (on the same line) gets swallowed up and ignored and provokes that warning. Does the processing of arguments to macros swallow up all the end-of-line markers or something? And if so, is there something I can do to make this work?

(One answer: I can use `\lstincludelisting`, which seems to work fine...but it's nice to see small (10 line?) listings right in place rather than by reference. And switching over involves editing dozens of documents, too.)

Comment: You're supplying `verbatim`-like content as part of a macro argument, and this is not allowed. Consider using the [`comment` package](http://ctan.org/pkg/comment) which does what you'll after - allowing versions to comment in/out certain environments.

Comment: Thanks. What makes the `listings` content "verbatim-like", and how could I have known this in advance?

Comment: Related: http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/159820/comment-sty-and-utf8-encoding

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You cannot pass a [`listings`](http://ctan.org/pkg/listings) environment - `lstlisting` or similar - as an argument to a macro (`\version` in your case) as `lstlisting` does a number of category code changes, all of which causes problems when gobbled as an argument. This is very similar in nature to supplying `verbatim`-like content as an argument, so see [Why doesn't `verbatim` work within ...?](http://www.tex.ac.uk/FAQ-verbwithin.html)

Instead of using "flags" as booleans, define a [`comment`](http://ctan.org/pkg/comment)-like environment that distinguishes between your "solution" and "non-solution" version:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{listings,comment}

\includecomment{solution}% Include solution environment
%\excludecomment{solution}% Exclude solution environment

\setlength{\parindent}{0pt}% Just for this example

\begin{document}

Before.

\begin{solution}
\begin{lstlisting}[language=C,basicstyle=\ttfamily]
#include <iostream.h>

main()
{
    cout << "Hello World!";
    return 0;
}
\end{lstlisting}
\end{solution}

After.

\end{document}
```

Compile the above as-is to obtain

[image]

Uncomment `\excludecomment{solution}` and compile to obtain

[image]

Comment: Thanks. THat's nice and clear. And to leave the exterior scripts that use this untouched, I can presumably use the "flag" to select the include/exclude options, since those are NOT verbatim-like. It does mean that I have to abandon my "\version{sol}" macro, though, and replace its braces with a begin/end pair, which is a pity (and a good deal of work).  Thanks for the explanation of why this is necessary.